# How do I use Firebase Preview Hosting on a branch which is not master?

Tags: git, firebase, firebase-hosting

Firebase recently announced Preview Channels, temporary hosting solution to share new upgrades to an app without making the counterpart install and run the entire project.

I already have Firebase Hosting for my master branch, that deploys to the main `X.web.app`. I'm trying to make a preview channel for a non-master branch Y, such that Firebase Preview Channel deploys to `X-Y-Z.web.app/` (where Z is some random hash, which is OK).

Every time I run

```
firebase hosting:channel:deploy Y
```

It just deploys my master branch, which is of no use to me because it's already deployed. Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase CLI doesn't know anything about your git branches.  It just knows about the files it sees in the directory where it runs.  If you want to deploy from another branch, you will have to check out that branch, then run the CLI.  I think you might find it helpful to write your own script that runs these commands automatically.

Comment: when I checkout <branch-name>, then use `firebase hosting:channel:deploy <branch-name>`, the deployed channel does not appear to be built from the branch. I changed the theme so I could easily tell the difference. I have committed my changes and run the same `build` script I use otherwise.

Comment: I know this is old but `<branch-name>` has nothing to do with your branch. That is just the name of the preview on firebase hosting which you can find by going to the console -> hosting -> your site -> scroll down to `preview channels` 

To deploy a branch, check it out as doug said then run the deploy command again. you can script it so its checkout staging branch -> deploy preview then checkout master branch -> deploy live

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant to the OP, but you can also set up a separate workflow that will automatically publish your app to standalone Preview Channels on each Pull Request in Github (no matter which branches are compared, it will automatically run on every PR for every branch on your repo).

Here is the guide on how to set this up: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration

If you configure this in line with the docs, you will get a separate `YAML` file (`.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml`) that will automatically trigger a build on each PR in Github and, if the build is successful, provide you with a randomly generated Preview link (e.g. *https://your-app-name--pr114-branch-to-compare-name-0mlyhw3v.web.app*) where you will be able to test your new features without direct impact on your main configuration running at your live channel.

The only disadvantage to this feature is that your Preview Channels will be deployed on top of the same database that your main (live) channel is linked to. I am not quite sure you can solve this and have a separate DB for testing Preview Channels otherwise than setting up a separate Firebase project strictly for testing purposes.

Here's an example of the `firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml` file for Preview Hosting in Firebase on Github PR that I ended up with on my React project:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
env:
  REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
              npm install
              npm run build --if-present
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_APPNAME }}'
          projectId: APPNAME
```